# Hover on the highest z-index overlapping divs

Tags: html, css

In the sample below, I understand that if I'm hovering over a `div` with `z-index:3` that I'm also technically hovering over those underneath it, so the `div` I'm hovering over and all its parents are affected by the `hover`

But how can I achieve a result where hovering over a div only affects that particular `div` and not those it's overlapping?

```css
.dragger:hover{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:1;">
        home
        <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:2;">
            home-1
            <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:3;">home-1-1</div>
            <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:3;">home-1-2</div>
            <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:3;">home-1-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:2;">
            home-2
            <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:3;">home-2-1</div>
            <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:3;">home-2-2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragger" draggable="true" style="z-index:1;">
        other
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make use of [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen that link just seems to be banging on about SVG stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a different class on the div you want the effect on. Right now they all have the same class, thus they all will be affected by the hover effect.

Comment: Ah, so for each "level" of div I'd have a `.dragger-1`, `.dragger-2` etc. - it works to an extent if I have different colours for each level but the underlying `div`s are also highlighted

Comment: Exactly. Just a reminder that you can assign many classes to an element separated by spaces like this: `class="dragger dragger-3"`. This way you can have general styles on the `dragger` class and specific ones on the `dragger-N` classes.